# ImageMagick %wx%h ... what other percentage stuff can you extract?

Tags: imagemagick

I am doing:

`identify -format "%w::%h::%@" "${file}" ?`

However, %@ does not give out %w or %h ... so what other stuff can I extract that is not documented?

I can not find any information on this:

https://imagemagick.org/script/identify.php

or  on

https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#geometry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ImageMagick see the long list of string formats that you can use:

https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php

You can also get others information from "%[fx:...]" using variables specified at:

https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php